# How to send text like "<>" in parameter with $.ajax to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

On client side i have form wich is send to server using `$.ajax`:

```
function showSearchResults(searchText, fromSuggestions) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Search",
        data: { searchText: searchText, fromSuggestions: fromSuggestions },
        success: function (response) {
            //processing response
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            showLoadingPane(); //function to show loading image
        }
    });
}
```

On server I have following code:

```
[HttpGet]
[AsyncAuthorize]
public ActionResult Search(string searchText, bool fromSuggestions = false)
{
    //handling request
}
```

When I type in form text **"<>"**, while debugging i see **"<>"** in js, but on server I am getting just empty string **""**

I tried to use `encodeURIComponent(searchText)` which gives me string **"%3C%3E"**, but on server i get **"3C3E"**

Comment: If it's safe to assume that an empty string should be translated to `<>` - then do that on the server.

Comment: This approach looks hacky.

Comment: sounds like you have some kind of input filtering on server. Could send as json

Comment: <> we can't pass in query string so i think it's may be problem here

Comment: Why don't you simply delete your question and answer? rather than `Question closed. We had custom model binder that was filtering some symbols`

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25090

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question closed. We had custom model binder that was filtering some symbols.